# Prototypal Inheritance in Javascript Working with Basic but not Complex Program

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

What is confusing is how this simple script works fine:

```
function A() {
    this.value = 0;
}
A.prototype.foo = function() {
    console.log(this.value);
};

function B() {
    this.value = 1;
    this.foo();
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.bar = function() {
    console.log(this instanceof A);
}
new B().bar();
// outputs 1, true
```

However, this larger script gives an error `this.loadDimensions is not a function`:
Basically, there is a `Player` class, which inherits from a `MovingComponent` class, which inherits from a `VisibleComponent` class. They all have methods attached to them.

```
  const PX_SZ = 4, MAX_HEIGHT = 100, MIN_HEIGHT = 300;
  var resources = {};
  resources.sprites = {};
  resources.sprites.player = new Image();
  resources.sprites.player.src = "resources/sprites/player.png";
  resources.sprites['default'] = new Image();
  resources.sprites['default'].src = "resources/sprites/default.png";
  resources.sprites.items = {};
  resources.sprites.backgroundEntities = {};
  var itemsTemp = ['default', 'coin0'];
  for (var i=0; i<itemsTemp.length; i++) {
      var item = itemsTemp[i];
      resources.sprites.items[item] = new Image();
      resources.sprites.items[item].src = "resources/sprites/items/" + item + ".png";
  }
  var backgroundEntitiesTemp = ['tree0'];
  for (var i=0; i<backgroundEntitiesTemp.length; i++) {
      var ent = backgroundEntitiesTemp[i];
      resources.sprites.backgroundEntities[ent] = new Image();
      resources.sprites.backgroundEntities[ent].src = "resources/sprites/background-entities/" + ent + ".png";
  }

  var canvas, ctx;
  var player = new Player();
  var keys = {};
  var game = new Game(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000));
  var world = new World();

  /** @class */
  function Game(seed) {
     this.seed = seed;
  }
  /** @class */
  function World() {
     this.gravity = 0.4;
     this.chances = {
         items: {
             coin0: 0.005
         },
         backgroundEntities: {
             tree0: 0.05
         }
     };
     this.itemsFloating = [];
     this.backgroundEntities = [];
     // for spawning
     this.exploredRightBound = 0;
     this.exploredLeftBound = 0;
  }
  World.prototype.generate = function(left, right) {
       if (left >= right) throw "left >= right in World#generate(left,right)";
       for (x = left; x < right; x += PX_SZ) {
           // world generation code here
           // coin0
           var level = getGroundHeightAt(x)
           if (Math.random() <= this.chances.items.coin0) {
              var item = new ItemFloating("coin0", x, level-20);
              this.itemsFloating.push(item);
           }
           if (Math.random() <= this.chances.backgroundEntities.tree0) {
              var ent = new BackgroundEntity("tree0", x, level-resources.sprites.backgroundEntities.tree0.height);
              this.backgroundEntities.push(ent);
           }
       }
 };
  /**
   *    @class
   *    anything that has a sprite attached to it
   */
  function VisibleComponent() {
     this.sprite = resources.sprites['default'];
  }
  VisibleComponent.prototype.loadDimensions = function() {
      console.log('load');
  };
  VisibleComponent.prototype.draw = function() {
     ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  };

  /** @class */
  function Item(name="default") {
   VisibleComponent.call(this);
     this.name = name || "default";
     this.sprite = resources.sprites.items[name];
     this.loadDimensions();
  }
  Item.prototype = Object.create(VisibleComponent.prototype);
  /** @class */
  function ItemFloating(name, x, y) {
   Item.call(this, name);
   this.name = name;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.loadDimensions(); // (when ready of now)
  }
  ItemFloating.prototype = Object.create(Item.prototype);
  /** @class */
  function BackgroundEntity(name="default", x=0, y=0) {
   VisibleComponent.call(this);
     this.name = name;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.width = 1;
     this.height = 1;
     this.sprite = resources.sprites.backgroundEntities[this.name];
     this.loadDimensions();
  }
  BackgroundEntity.prototype = Object.create(VisibleComponent.prototype);
  /** @class */
  function MovingEntity(x=0, y=0) {
   VisibleComponent.call(this);
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.width = 1;
     this.height = 1;
  }
  MovingEntity.prototype = Object.create(VisibleComponent.prototype);
  MovingEntity.prototype.collisionWith = function(ent) {
     return ((this.x>=ent.x&&this.x<=ent.x+ent.width) || (ent.x>=this.x&&ent.x<=this.x+this.width))
        &&  ((this.y>=ent.y&&this.y<=ent.y+ent.height) || (ent.y>=this.y&&ent.y<=this.y+this.height));
  };
  /** @class */
  function Player() {
   MovingEntity.call(this);
   this.inventory = {};
   console.log(this instanceof VisibleComponent);
   this.speed = 4;
   this.jumpSpeed = 8;
   this.vspeed = 0;
   this.sprite = resources.sprites.player;
     this.loadDimensions();
     this.direction = "right";
  }
  Player.prototype = Object.create(MovingEntity.prototype);
  Player.prototype.draw = function() {
     ctx.save();
     ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
     if (this.direction == "left") ctx.scale(-1, 1);    // flip over y-axis
     ctx.translate(-this.sprite.width, 0);
     ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
     ctx.restore();
  }
  Player.prototype.move = function() {
     if (keys['ArrowLeft']) {
        this.x -= this.speed;
        this.direction = "left";
        var leftEdge = this.x-canvas.width/2-this.width/2;
        if (leftEdge < world.exploredLeftBound) {
           world.generate(leftEdge, world.exploredLeftBound);
           world.exploredLeftBound = leftEdge;
        }
     }
     if (keys['ArrowRight']) {
        this.x += this.speed;
        this.direction = "right";
        var rightEdge = this.x+canvas.width/2+this.width/2;
        if (rightEdge > world.exploredRightBound) {
            world.generate(world.exploredRightBound, rightEdge);
            world.exploredRightBound = rightEdge;
        }
     }

     var level = getGroundHeightAt(this.x+this.width/2);

     if (this.y + this.height < level) {
        this.vspeed -= world.gravity;
     } else if (this.y + this.height > level) {
        this.y = level - this.height;
        this.vspeed = 0;
     }
     if (keys[' '] && this.y+this.height == getGroundHeightAt(this.x+this.width/2)) this.vspeed += this.jumpSpeed;

     this.y -= this.vspeed;
     for (var i=0; i<world.itemsFloating.length; i++) {
        var item = world.itemsFloating[i];
        if (this.collisionWith(item)) {
            if (this.inventory.hasOwnProperty(item.name)) this.inventory[item.name]++;
            else this.inventory[item.name] = 1;
            world.itemsFloating.splice(i, 1);
        }
     }
 };
```

I'm fairly new to javascript inheritance, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Also, since the first script worked, I figured there's something I'm just overlooking in my second script. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
In the beginning of the file, I declare `player` as a `new Player()`. `resources` contains `Image` instances that point to various image files. `ctx` and `canvas` are pretty self-explanatory globals.

Also, `player` isn't recognized as an instance of `MovingEntity` or `VisibleComponent`, even though `Player`'s `prototype` is set to `Object.create(MovingEntity.prototype)`, which has its `prototype` set to `Object.create(VisibleComponent.prototype)`.

One other thing to mention is that in the definition of `loadDimensions()` in `VisibleComponent`, either the `onload` property of `this.sprite` is set to a function, or `addEventListener()` is called for `'load'`, depending on whether `this.sprite` has loaded (`width != 0`) or not.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description. What is the error or issue?

Comment: Your code looks fine. What part works in the basic program but not in the complex one?

Comment: My bad @DarkFalcon I was in a rush. It's in the question now. And @Bergi, it doesn't give error `this.loadDimensions is not a function`

Comment: Where, in the `Player` constructor? Can you show us how you called that?

Comment: I don't get that when I set `window.resources` to something and call `var p = new Player();`. We need more information please.

Comment: Alright, @Bergi the error is thrown in the `Player()` constructor right after `this.sprite` is set. `resources` is just set to an object of the `Image`'s, @MikeMcCaughan. Should I post the full code?

Comment: Try `new Player()` instead of `Player()`… Otherwise, yes, please post the complete code that is necessary to reproduce the error (but strip away the parts that aren't)

Comment: Where are you talking about with `new Player()`, @Bergi. And yes, I'll post the full code (except for extraneous functions that are declared after the classes and shouldn't affect them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the beginning of the file, I declare `player` as a `new Player()`.

That's the problem, you need to call the constructor *after* having set up your class. It currently doesn't throw an error about `Player` not being a function because the declaration is hoisted, but the prototype is not yet initialised with the value you expect so it indeed does not have a `.loadDimensions()` method yet.

Comment: That makes sense. It works now. I forgot javascript was like this.